Какие бы красивые слова и образы вы НЕ/НИ подобрали…
Встретилось в комментариях к вопросу «Насколько верно изобразил С. Я. Маршак идею Шекспира в сонете 16?» неправильное, как мне показалось, использование частицы «не» в этом предложении: «…Если ваш текст написан без опоры на литературное произведение, то "зачета" не видать, какие бы красивые слова и образы вы не подобрали». 5uglov.ru/post/… –
Решил, что автор комментария неправильно воспроизвёл цитату, но пройдя по ссылке 5uglov…, выяснил, что и в цитируемой статье использовано такое же написание:






Сам бы не задумываясь написал бы это предложение с «ни» (какие бы красивые слова и образы вы ни подобрали), а написание с «не» в придаточном счёл бы ошибкой, но вот то, что в статье, написанной «вместе с экспертом по проверке итоговых сочинений» использовано именно «не», несколько поколебало мою уверенность.
Чем можно объяснить выбор авторами статьи частицы НЕ вместо НИ в придаточном предложении?

Этот вопрос похож на: "Что только люди (не|ни) придумывают?". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Ну а разве в той теме даётся ответ на вопрос, заданный мной здесь: «Чем можно объяснить выбор авторами статьи частицы НЕ вместо НИ в придаточном предложении?»

Слава, просто ошибка. Причем текст-то писал не сам эксперт. Эксперт всего лишь советует. А написание частиц не/ни в придаточных предложениях часто вызывает трудности.  Вы и сами знаете.

Усы и хвост мой аргумент, или Садитесь, единица.
Литературный аргумент - это, пожалуй, основной и обязательный критерий. Если ваш текст написан без опоры на литературное произведение, то "зачета" не видать, какие бы красивые слова и образы вы ни подобрали.
Слазив на страничку и осмотревшись, я не узрела в контексте ничего, что указывало бы, критерием чего является аргумент. Если текст слаб на голову, а именно это мы наблюдаем, то - всё, это кранты, это конец. С бодуна сочинён, набран, вычитан, проэкспертирован.
Не надо бояться себя. Напротив, никогда не разговаривайте с незнакомцами.

Итак, литературные аргументы – вот кто пострадал в этой теме. Надо защищать! У меня есть хорошая книга издательства Эксмо 2017 год: Полное собрание литературных аргументов. Всё по делу, и вот главный раздел из семи обозначенных: Нравственно-философские и этические проблемы. А там 23 темы: Разум и чувство, Честь и бесчестие, Добро и зло, Духовность и т. д.  И для каждой темы литературные примеры. Что же еще читать-то, чтобы стать нравственным человеком!
Ведь сказал же поэт:  "Ни одно философское учение не наставит вас, как стать честным человеком, лучше и скорее, чем чтение Вергилия".
Это да, а у нас вот проблемы с НЕ и НИ, сомнения и колебания...
Правильно: «…Если ваш текст написан без опоры на литературное произведение, то "зачета" не видать, какие бы красивые слова и образы вы НИ подобрали».
Это классика темы: СПП с уступительным значением (усилительная частица НИ). Не увидите зачет, хотя и подберете самые  красивые слова. Нет отрицания, но есть усиление.
Пояснение
Честно говоря, на школьном этапе изучения этой темы у меня тоже были сомнения, но теперь я могу предложить вам методику, которая поможет от этих сомнений избавиться. Это грамматика! Надо всего лишь определить вид синтаксической конструкции.
А методика здесь

Объяснение начинает смутно напрашиваться, если посмотреть дальше на пример литературного аргумента:


Что не так здесь? Вы имеете в виду тире перед отрицанием?

да. я же подчеркнул красным

Здесь нет ошибки. У Розенталя: "Примечание. Обычно тире не ставится... если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание не... Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое..." (http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92) Из Нацкорпуса: Но это звучание — не главное в стихе (В. Шаламов); А Джеф Томпсон сказал, что бюджеты — не главное в ролике... ("Рекламный мир"); Ты права, дорогая, страсть — не главное в нашей любви... (М. Пришвин).

ну спасибо, интонациорнное тире значит, я так и думал с самого начала, но потом решил свериться с правилом, чето нагуглил, а там про интонацию ни гугу, нет и все понимаешь.
